# openerp dpQuery is not defined

Tags: odoo

Occasionally when I click a menu to open up a list view, there will be a Dialog popup window showing:

```
    OpenERP Client error
    Uncaught ReferenceError: dpQuery is not defined
    :1
```

It has happened for about two or three weeks. It is very annoying, because:

1. There is no special or known condition when this error occurs.
2. I get no clue with chrome java script debug function.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer today. It seems being related to DealPly.

There is a javascript segment above body as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="__DealPly_code_848315.9618917853" async="" defer="">if(typeof DealPlyUI === 'undefined'){eval(unescape('try%7Bwindow.DealPlyConfigLocal%3Dfunction%28%29%20%7B%7D%3Bwindow.DealPlyConfigLocal.getPartner%3Dfunction%28%29%7Breturn%20%27%27%3B%7D%3Bwindow.DealPlyConfigLocal.getChannel%3Dfunction%28%29%7Breturn%20%27%27%3B%7D%3Bwindow.DealPlyConfigLocal.getHardId%3Dfunction%28%29%7Breturn%20%27v24872288332457237946232013081909390033%27%3B%7D%3Bwindow.DealPlyConfigLocal.getHardIdSource%3Dfunction%28%29%7Breturn%20%27%27%3B%7D%3Bwindow.DealPlyConfigLocal.getVehicle%3Dfunction%28%29%7Breturn%20%27crx%27%3B%7D%3Bwindow.DealPlyConfigLocal.getCountryCode%3Dfunction%28%29%7Breturn%20%27CN%27%3B%7D%3B%7Dcatch%28e%29%7B%7D;'));eval(unescape(';'));} if(typeof dpLock === undefined || typeof dpLock === 'undefined'  ) {   var dpLock = 0 ; var interDp = setInterval(function(){ if(dpQuery('.dealply-toast').size() > 0 || dpLock > 10){clearInterval(interDp);}  dpLock++;   eval(unescape('%20%20;')); },200);} </script>
```